# $routeParams undefined when passing to new view & controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

Fairly new to AngularJS and WebAPI here, and figure the best way to learn is by doing. Apologies in advance if this question seems simple - I've spent a day flipping through StackOverflow and tried them all.

I currently have a separate Master & Detail view, both with their own controller. I am trying to pass the selected ID through to the Details controller so I can query my database using the ID, though am getting "undefined" on my $routeParams. I'm unsure if I am  missing something simple, or whether I'm even approaching this correctly.

The controller doesn't seem to like it when I inject '$routeParams' either.

My app.js module:

```
var app = angular.module("ProjectDashboardModule", ["ngRoute"]);
app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $routeProvider
        .when("/", { templateUrl: "/Home/Index" })
        .when("/Project", { templateUrl: '/Project/Index', controller: 'ProjectCrudController' })
        .when("/Project/project/:id", {templateUrl:'/Project/project', controller: 'ProjectTaskController' });

    $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/home' });
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);
```

my Factory.js:

```
app.factory('projectFactory', ['$http', function ($http) {
    var urlBase = '/api/Projects/';
    var projectFactory = {};

    projectFactory.getProjects = function () {
        return $http.get(urlBase);
    };    
    projectFactory.getSingleProject = function (id) {
        return $http.get(urlBase + '/' + id);
    };    
    return projectFactory;
}]);
```

my ProjectTaskController.js:

```
app.controller('ProjectTaskController', ['$scope', "$routeParams", 'projectFactory', function ($scope, $routeParams, projectFactory) {
    alert($routeParams.id)
    $scope.project;
    $scope.message;
    getProjectById($routeParams.id);    

    function getProjectById(id) {
        projectFactory.getSingleProject(id)
        .success(function (data) {
            $scope.project = data;
        })
        .error(function (error) {
            $scope.message = 'error retrieving project ' + error.message;
        });
    }
 }]);
```

Comment: is `$route.current.params.id` any different?

Comment: do you have a `<base href="index.html" />` defined in your index.html?

Comment: try this..I think this might be why: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location#relative-links since your code looks fine to me

Comment: I'll check it out. I have a feeling that I have my views & routing set up incorrectly.  Trying to find a good resource to confirm that. Since i'm not using SPA, but instead having multiple mini-SPAs

Comment: Its basically saying set your base href if you haven't already

Comment: Do you have something like: <script src="/vendor/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>?  Verify it's actually being downloaded.

Comment: I do have that, and do see it loaded correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that my problem was that all my angular script references were scattered. I moved all my custom script references (controller, factory, module) to index.cshtml and fixed the issue.